# My async func inside for loop is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

I have a code that gets all Item Prices from a database and then makes an API call to update them.

For some reason, loop inside my Button1_click function doesn't work but similar code without the loop on Button2_click will work fine. I cant understand why.

I can see the results of the API calls in the output. It seems like API is called but the price is never updated.

It is my first time dealing with Async functions and Task so I m a newbie at this.

```
    protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = DB_GetItemPrice();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)        
        {
            var task = SendRequestAsync(dt.Rows[i]);
            var items = await task;
            Debug.WriteLine(task.Result);
        }            

    }
    protected async void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = DB_GetItemPrice();

        var dr = dt.Rows[0];
        var task = SendRequestAsync(dr);
        var items = await task;
        Debug.WriteLine(task.Result);

    }
    protected DataTable DB_GetItemPrice()
    {
        var db = PSystem.DataHelp.Database.Application;
        var con = new DbConnection(db, ConnectionState.Open);
        var st =
            "SELECT * " +
            "FROM item_discount ";
        var cmd = new PSystem.DataHelp.DbCommand(st, con);

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var dt = PSystem.DataHelp.DbManager.GetDataTable(reader);
            if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count < 1)
                return null;
            return dt;                 
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> SendRequestAsync(DataRow dr)
    {
        string APICall;
        string OrderID = ((long)dr["OrderID"]).ToString();
        string GoodsID = ((long)dr["GoodsID"]).ToString();
        string NewPrice = ((long)dr["NewPrice"]).ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(OrderID + "  ," + GoodsID + "  ," + NewPrice);
        APICall = "myAPIAdress?" + "&Param0=" + GoodsID  + "," + 3 + "," + NewPrice + "," + 1 + "," + OrderID + ",,";

        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var Message = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(APICall).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return Message;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The loop isn't parallel, you'll want to store these task in a list or something of sorts and then do `Task.WhenAll`. Something like:  `var tasks = new List<Task<string>>(); await Tasks.WhenAll(tasks);`. You will add your task to the list inside your loop and then outside of the loop call the `Tasks.WhenAll(tasks);`. There's no guaranteed order they will finish, it will wait until all task have been completed.

Comment: I tried to add all the task to a list as you suggested but still no luck.

    `protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt = DB_GetItemPrice();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)        
            {
                var task = SendRequestAsync(dt.Rows[i]);
                activeTasks.Add(task);
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(activeTasks);

        }`

Comment: There are some problems with your code that might be need to be fixed first as they are  maybe part of the problem. Like opening multiple Connections but never closing them. Is "myAPIAdress?" a placeholder but not real code?  DB_GetItemPrice can return null but you expected a valid object.

Comment: I just didnt want to reveal the API address. There is another value there. I m sure the DB doesnt return null. I can see all the DataTable's returning their values in the output. `Debug.WriteLine(OrderID + "  ," + GoodsID + "  ," + NewPrice);` Even if these were to cause the issues, my Button1_Click wouldnt also work right?

Comment: Async is not so easy, i suggest you to check your code without async and when functional you migrate to async

Comment: "It seems like API is called but the price is never updated." That sounds like a problem with the API. Have you ruled that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that my original code is working fine.

Probably API I tried to request has some sort of rate limiting or such. When I just give a second delay in between each tasks using `await Task.Delay(1000)`, it works fine.